# Nested Querying in mongodb datase

Tags: java, mongodb

I am bit new to mongodb and also in java. I want to query the key breaktime and find the sum of the value.

```
 db.users90.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ad5f2e2f58a542f7989e8fc"),
    "date" : "2018-04-17",
    "break" : [
            {
                    "out" : "18:00",
                    "in" : "18:40",
                    "breaktime" : "0:40"
            },
            {
                    "out" : "19:00",
                    "in" : "19:30",
                    "breaktime" : "0:30"
            }
    ]
}
```

I need a help in java, to add those 2 breaktime keys(some cases it may be n number of documents in break)
0:40+0:30 = 0:70 minutes

Thanks,
Mohan

Comment: If you want to add them, why you're storing them as string?

Answer (score 0):

Although the query you need is simple, having your "breaktime" values stored as `String`, makes everything difficult and complex for no reason.

So, assuming you have stored these values as numbers *e.g. double*, you could easily execute your query in Java like this;

```
AggregateIterable aggregationQuery = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
        new Document("$match", new Document("date","yourDate")), // match a document with a specific date
        new Document("$unwind", "$break"), // decompose the 'break' array
        new Document("$group", new Document("_id", null).
              append("totalBreakTime", new Document("$sum","$break.breaktime")) 
)));
if (aggregationQuery.iterator().hasNext()){
      double totalBreakTime = ((Document)aggregationQuery.iterator().next()).get("break",Document.class).getDouble("breakTime");
}
```